# spliiting a set of documents in to three disjoint sets of fixed number

Tags: java, python, bash, sampling

I have a set of documents containing some thousands of documents. I would like to split it into 3 sets whose number is different but fixed. How would i do it?Any script bash/python/java or link to a reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more information? What do you mean by "number". A "number" in the file name? Or "number" as in quantity? What have you tried yourself to do?

Comment: take the first element, put it in a set.  Take the second element, put it in a set.  Take the rest of the elements, put them in a set.  Now you have 3 sets with fixed numbers of elements ... I'm afraid you're going to have to be a little more descriptive about what you want ...

Comment: number means number of documents. You can think of splitting a dataset set into training,test and development set

Comment: i am looking for a tools if there is one

Comment: How do you determine which set a document is supposed to be in?  And what format is your original set stored as?  Is it a text file, a directory?

Comment: its random sampling.but the number of documents are fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you can randomly take documents, then in python, I would simply use list slicing on the "`set`":

```
 set_of_documents = ...  #somehow build the set
 list_of_documents = list(set_of_documents)
 training = list_of_documents[:ntraining] 
 development = list_of_documents[-ndev:]
 test = list_of_documents[ntraining:-ndev]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
docs={'doc1','doc2','doc3','doc4','doc5','doc6','doc7','doc8','doc9','doc10','doc11','doc12'}
training=set()
test=set()
dev=set()
lis=list(docs)
print(lis)
try:
    for i in range(0,len(lis),3):
        print(lis[i])
        training.add(lis[i])
        test.add(lis[i+1])
        dev.add(lis[i+2])
except IndexError:
    pass

print(training,test,dev)



**output:**

    {'doc10', 'doc3', 'doc8', 'doc7'} {'doc1', 'doc11', 'doc9', 'doc4'} {'doc2', 'doc12', 'doc6', 'doc5'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given array `documents` containing your data, and an array `partitions` specifying how many documents to put into each list:

```
import random
def partition_docs(documents, partitions):
        if len(documents) != sum(partitions):
                raise ValueError("Need exactly %d documents for these partitions, have %d" % (sum(partitions), len(documents)))
        random.shuffle(documents)
        results = []
        start = 0
        for num in partitions:
                results.append(documents[start:start+num])
                start += num
        return results
```

**Explanation**: `random.shuffle` totally randomizes the list of documents. Then you simply get consecutive slices and return them as separate lists. This easily guarantees you have the number of documents you want and also ensures the distribution is as random as it can get. This also works for any number of lists to split the documents into.

**Sample usage**:

```
documents = [random.choice("abcdefghijklmn") for _ in xrange(100)]
partitions = [10, 50, 40]

print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
```

Output:

```
[['b', 'n', 'm', 'l', 'c', 'j', 'l', 'e', 'i', 'f'], ['k', 'n', 'i', 'b', 'k', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'd', 'd', 'm', 'g', 'i', 'd', 'i', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'k', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'm', 'k', 'c', 'h', 'k', 'j', 'k', 'g', 'f', 'j', 'l', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'c', 'd', 'n', 'b', 'h', 'm', 'm'], ['a', 'g', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'k', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'f', 'd', 'j', 'h', 'h', 'k', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'h', 'm', 'i', 'c', 'i', 'c', 'g', 'm', 'l', 'a', 'j', 'g', 'd', 'd', 'n', 'b', 'b', 'n', 'k']]
[['m', 'n', 'e', 'a', 'k', 'b', 'm', 'd', 'k', 'f'], ['d', 'h', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'k', 'b', 'g', 'n', 'd', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'm', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'b', 'j', 'l', 'k', 'f', 'c', 'j', 'i', 'n', 'j', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'm', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'f', 'l'], ['m', 'i', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'b', 'e', 'k', 'k', 'h', 'd', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'k', 'f', 'c', 'l', 'g', 'm', 'f', 'n', 'c', 'i', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'k', 'n', 'j', 'b', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'g']]
[['f', 'f', 'l', 'g', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'h'], ['i', 'k', 'm', 'b', 'c', 'h', 'k', 'i', 'd', 'k', 'n', 'n', 'f', 'c', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'm', 'e', 'j', 'k', 'n', 'd', 'g', 'a', 'g', 'j', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'i', 'f', 'j', 'm', 'i', 'd', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'h', 'c'], ['g', 'h', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'n', 'i', 'd', 'l', 'b', 'l', 'f', 'a', 'j', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'k', 'm', 'g', 'j', 'j', 'm', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'n', 'k', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'd']]
[['h', 'k', 'b', 'l', 'h', 'g', 'g', 'n', 'm', 'c'], ['g', 'a', 'i', 'c', 'f', 'i', 'd', 'i', 'k', 'h', 'j', 'b', 'f', 'k', 'm', 'd', 'g', 'm', 'b', 'h', 'f', 'c', 'h', 'd', 'f', 'j', 'n', 'l', 'k', 'n', 'k', 'b', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'b', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'l', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'f', 'm', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'g', 'k'], ['d', 'e', 'm', 'f', 'a', 'l', 'n', 'd', 'j', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'g', 'n', 'k', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'j', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'e', 'm', 'e', 'a', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'k', 'k', 'n', 'n']]
```

With different partitions:

```
partitions = [30, 30, 40]

print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
print partition_docs(documents, partitions)
```

Output:

```
[['g', 'h', 'n', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'h', 'd', 'l', 'g', 'e', 'b', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'i', 'f', 'j', 'a', 'l', 'j', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'j', 'm', 'n'], ['c', 'm', 'g', 'm', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'e', 'm', 'k', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'f', 'd', 'm', 'b', 'm', 'i', 'k', 'd', 'l', 'j', 'f', 'n', 'd', 'l'], ['k', 'j', 'n', 'h', 'b', 'h', 'm', 'j', 'i', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'k', 'n', 'b', 'h', 'm', 'b', 'n', 'j', 'l', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'a', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'h', 'a', 'i', 'k', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'm', 'c', 'e']]
[['l', 'l', 'i', 'd', 'm', 'n', 'c', 'm', 'a', 'h', 'g', 'l', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'n', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'j', 'm', 'h', 'h', 'g', 'e', 'm', 'g', 'i', 'f', 'b'], ['n', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'h', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'k', 'c', 'h', 'g', 'j', 'a', 'k', 'n', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'j', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'k', 'c', 'm', 'e'], ['e', 'm', 'b', 'j', 'e', 'c', 'j', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'e', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'k', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'l', 'a', 'a', 'k', 'f', 'l', 'i', 'l', 'b', 'm', 'h', 'e', 'm', 'l', 'm', 'f', 'n', 'e', 'k']]
[['h', 'e', 'c', 'n', 'm', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'a', 'm', 'k', 'i', 'k', 'g', 'f', 'b', 'j', 'l', 'j', 'm', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'f', 'j'], ['m', 'j', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'd', 'm', 'l', 'g', 'i', 'e', 'm', 'i', 'j', 'f', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'n', 'j', 'j', 'e', 'c', 'k', 'm', 'e'], ['i', 'n', 'b', 'i', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'k', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'm', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'k', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'k']]
[['l', 'e', 'k', 'k', 'm', 'l', 'g', 'c', 'j', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'k', 'k', 'f', 'l', 'h', 'e', 'g', 'm', 'k', 'm', 'j', 'i', 'b', 'l', 'c', 'b', 'h', 'g'], ['e', 'j', 'd', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'm', 'b', 'h', 'j', 'h', 'm', 'j', 'j', 'i', 'i', 'f', 'e', 'l', 'n', 'i', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'a', 'h', 'i'], ['i', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'j', 'e', 'a', 'h', 'h', 'b', 'h', 'l', 'a', 'i', 'm', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'i', 'm', 'k', 'n', 'g', 'l', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'j', 'h', 'n', 'k', 'k', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for machine learning purposes, I believe it would be wise *not* to use slicing as you may introduce some bias (documents may have been sorted following a certain logic). So I would go with Claudiu shuffle solution.

Note that if you simply want some proportions to be satisfied and not exact sets size you may compute the probability of each document to belong to each set:

```
import random
def split(documents, prob_training=0.8, prob_test=0.1, prob_dev=0.1):
    #you may check some rules on input probabilities e.g. that they indeed *are* probabilities
    training = []
    test = []
    dev = []
    for document in documents:
        prob = random.random()
        if prob < prob_training:
            training.append(document)
        elif prob < prob_training + prob_test:
            test.append(document)
        elif prob < prob_training + prob_test + prob_dev:
            dev.append(document)
    return training, test, dev
```